# Select specific files with their name in folders then manipulate them (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a script to select specific files from their names in several folders and them copy those files in a new folder.

More precisely, I have a directory that contains 29 folders, in each folders there are hundreds of '*.fits' files.

I want to select among those fits files those which do not have the numbers '4' or '8' in the last 3 digits before .fits

For example: "ngc6397id016000520jd2456870p5705f002.fits" has '002' as last three digits before the extension .fits

I am kind of lost here as I am pretty new to this, can anyone help ?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far in your solution attempts. This will make it more likely that your question can be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

data_path = ".<your directory with 29 folders>"
data_dir = os.listdir(data_path)
# for each folder in the directory
for fits_dir in data_dir:
    fits_path = data_path + "/" + log_dir + "/"
    # for each .fits file in the folder
    for file in os.listdir(fits_path):
        # if neither 4 or 8 are in the last 3 digits before the dot 
        if '4' not in file.split(".")[0][-3:] and '8' not in file.split(".")[0][-3:]:
             shutil.copy(fits_path + "/" + file, destination)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just had to add one line and it was it ! Works great !

Answer (score 1):

SO is for code help, however, this should get you started.

The below code will print out the desired files by traversing all subdirectories and contained files. There are improvements you must make to this code for it to be reliable; such as error and case checking, however, it will serve to get you going.

```
import os

TARGET_DIR = r"C:\yourDir"
IGNORE_NUM = ['4', '8']

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(TARGET_DIR):
    for index, file in enumerate(files):
        fileSplit = os.path.splitext(file)
        if(fileSplit[1] != ".fits"):
            continue
        lastThree = fileSplit[0][-3:]
        if(set(IGNORE_NUM).intersection(set(lastThree))):
            continue
        print(f"[{index}] {file}")
```

From that, it is trivial to copy the file over to your desired directory using the [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) library.

`shutil.copyfile(src, dst)`

Combine all of that and you have your script.

Comment: I tried your code and even though that's not what I used, it helped me, thank you !